# Is it possible Receive Money from Authorize.net direct to bank

Tags: international-transfer, wire-transfer

i have a question. I just work for my client that currently stay in Dubai, after the project done they said want to send me the money.
They ask for my bank account, swift code, my name and address.

After that they send me a screen shot, the picture is screenshot from **Authorize.net**. when I see the picture receipt, the content is: in Merchant section is their Name, and in the Billing Info there is My Name, bank account and swift code. Below is the nominal we have deal.

But I'm not sure Authorize.net can do that. I'm afraid that they are scammers.

Is it possible we receive money directly to our bank from Authorize.net?

Comment: Quite apart from the question you are asking, the screenshot you describe sounds like a transfer in the wrong direction.  Authorize.net is a payment processor that takes money from the "billing info" (you), and sends it to the merchant (them).  On top of that, the screenshot could even be totally fake.  You should definitely talk to your bank and make sure to stop any withdrawal in progress.

Comment: @BenVoigt is it possible without my authorization to do that? because in  Indonesia, all Debit Card not able to use for online transaction